# QButtonBox set default button

Tags: qt, user-interface

Under Qt 5.3, the default button of a QButtonBox is `Cancel` and I want to set it to `Ok` but I can't find a way to achieve it. I've tried this :

```
QPushButton * b = ui->buttonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::Ok);
b->setDefault(true);
```

but with no success, it throws :

```
/Users/thomas/Dev/Joker/app/Joker/RulerSpaceDialog.cpp:18:3: error: member access into incomplete type 'QPushButton'
        b->setDefault(true);
         ^
/Applications/Qt/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qdialog.h:50:7: note: forward declaration of 'QPushButton'
class QPushButton;
      ^
1 error generated.
```

I also try by browsing the list but with no luck....

## EDIT :

I added the include to get that code :

```
QPushButton * b = ui->buttonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::Ok);
if(b)
{
    b->setDefault(true);
    qDebug() << b->text();
}
```

Which outputs `Ok` waits 2secs then highlight the `Cancel` button...

Comment: Your code looks correct. Just include `#include <QPushButton>` into your header/source file.

Comment: Can't test at the moment, but do you need to turn default off for the cancel button as well to avoid having two default buttons?

Comment: @A.E.Drew doesn't work either

Comment: Do I get it right? Did you want only 1 OK button?

Comment: @Tay2510 I've got `Ok` and `Cancel` buttons. The default one is `Cancel` and I'd like to put `Ok` as default

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you set [auto default](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#autoDefault-prop) `false` as well, use `setAutoDefault(false)` as well as `setDefault(false)`.

Example code below.

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QDialogButtonBox* bb = new QDialogButtonBox(
    QDialogButtonBox::Ok | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);

  QPushButton* okBtn = bb->button(QDialogButtonBox::Ok);
  okBtn->setAutoDefault(true);
  okBtn->setDefault(true);

  QPushButton* caBtn = bb->button(QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);
  caBtn->setAutoDefault(false);
  caBtn->setDefault(false);

  QDialog dlg;
  QVBoxLayout* dlgLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
  dlgLayout->addWidget(bb);
  dlg.setLayout(dlgLayout);
  dlg.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

When I tested this on Windows, the OK button was the default button by default, but I could swap that to the cancel button by changing the calls to `setAutoDefault` and `setDefault`.

Comment: This is almost ok, I just added the focus on OkButton using  `okBtn->setFocus();`